# HeidiSQL number of rows in table doesn't correspond to the number of lines inserted with Talend tMySQLoutput

Tags: mysql, insert, talend, heidisql

I'm running a job in Talend which empties a table "A", extracts data from several databases, makes some transformations on it and then inserts the data in this table "A".

When I run the job, I've no error, and with the statistics option in the run tab, I can see that my job inserts **9278** rows in my table A. But when I run HeidiSQL, I execute this sql query `SELECT count(*) FROM table A` and the result is **9261**.

I've no idea why I have this problem, I've already done a lot of research on the web but I found nothing.

**edit:**

I've execute my sql query directly in talend with a tMySQLinput (and a TLogRow to see the result of it) at the end of the job and the result is **9278** so I think the issue is in HeidiSQL.

Comment: What are you doing/using to "empty" the table in your Talend job? Can you try running the same `COUNT(*)` query in Talend through a tMySQLInput component just to check there's not an issue with HeidiSQL?

Comment: I use a tMySQLrow components to execute my delete query.

Comment: What delete query are you using? Is it a straight `DELETE FROM A` or a `TRUNCATE A` Are you sure your table is empty before you add data to it?

Comment: It *could* be caused by the default isolation level (in case you are using `delete` instead of `truncate`) try to run a `commit` or `rollback` in your SQL client and then run the `select count(*)` again.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR: I'm using a 'DELETE FROM A' but I can't use a 'TRUNCATE A' because there's conditions in my query. And my table is totally empty before the insert.

Comment: What conditions? Surely if you're not deleting everything then your table by definition won't be empty. @a_horse_with_no_name Talend's default behaviour is to commit at the end of a job or after a set amount of processed records and you have to explicitly not call a commit to avoid this so I would expect that this is not the case but it's a good call nonetheless.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: I've try that but it didn't change anything.

Comment: Yes but in this case (Development, not production), the table is empty after the 'DELETE'. And this is my query : 'DELETE FROM dm_ventes_lignes_factures_talend WHERE dim_societe_id = "+((Integer)globalMap.get("societe_id"))+" AND a_effacer = 1'.
But I put a tMysqlCommit after the insert because it wasn't commit at the end of the job.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR: I'm not talking about commit in Talend, I'm talking about a commit in **HeidiSQL**. The default isolation level is repeatable-read. Which means the transaction inside HeidiSQL does not see committed changes that were committed *after* the transaction started. So in order to see the effect of a commit from another transaction you must end the one in the HeidiSQL. And the only way to do that is through `commit` or `rollback` (or using auto commit)